# Proving a certain inequality of supremums and infimums

Tags: calculus, abstract-algebra, inequality

Let $f:[a,b]\to R$ be a bounded and integrable function.
Prove that if $M_f=sup\{f(x)|x\in [a,b]\}$ and $m_f=inf\{f(x)|x\in [a,b]\}$ then $M_{|f|} - m_{|f|} \leq M_f - m_f$.

I tried more than a few attempts, the closest I got was:
$M_f \geq m_f$ and $M_{|f|} \geq M_f$ and also $m_{|f|} \geq m_f$
therefore $M_f - m_f \geq m_f - m_{|f|}$

But I couldn't find a way to plug the $M_{|f|}$ in a way that makes sense.
Can someone help me solve this using this method (supremums and infimums)? It seems pretty trivial

Comment: An almost identical question was asked recently: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4112581/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4113202/42969.

Comment: Perhaps a better link (which seems to do essentially what I do below) is: [the answer to this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4092347/proving-f-riemann-integrable-implies-f-riemann-integrable-by-contradiction/4092394#4092394)